# Can't find the custom framework path in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, module

Version : XCode 6.1.1   language: Objective-C

Sorry, I had a problem about the create custom framework in iOS with Objective-C.

I encounter the file can't build module "frameworkName".

My data structure like below. There have a real folder in my folder about FolderFileFramework project(It is custom framework project).
[image]

And I had new group (same of the folder name ).

I wrote the

```
  #import <UtilityFolder/CustomUtils.h>
```

in the " FolderFileFramework.h"

[image]

Then, I write a simply code in my framework file.

(Because my code is complex,so I write these simply)

[image]

It is implement file, just show log.
[image]

Then I drag the CustomUtils.h file to the public, offer the show for use file.

[image]

Then I change dynamic library to static library.
[image]

Now, I compile the framework and drag the framework file to "UseFramework project".

But when I import the

```
 #import <FolderFileFramework/FolderFileFramework.h>
```

It will show " Could not build module 'FolderFileFramwork'.

[image]

We can see the "FolderFileFramework.h" file in the Headers.

They have

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import <UtilityFolder/CustomUtils.h>
```

[image]

I don't know why I can't build the module 'FolderFileFramwork' in my "useFramwwork project".

I think it is the path include the folder(UtilityFolder) reason.

But I don't know how the fix the import the path.

Have anyone know how how to resolve?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This may not strictly be the answer as it's hard to guess what's happening without touching the project. I've used this to generate static framework: https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework, maybe it will help you too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, I restart the XCode, and set the Architecture to armv7s. Then go to the Build setting → set  Build Active Architecture Only to "No". Then I compile the framework will correct for iphone 4s~ iphone6 plus.